# Prevent session creation on rails 3.2.2 for RESTful api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, warden, session-storage

How can i prevent the session store from creating a session on JSON/XML calls ?

My problem is that i save sessions in a database and it gets flooded on multiple api calls.

I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and Devise for authentication.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275008/how-to-conditionally-assign-actioncontrollerbase-session-in-rails-2-3-3

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003667/rails-3-disable-session-cookies

Comment: everything is pointing at https://github.com/kares/session_off. it just doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My problem here was with Warden inside Devise. I had to "tell" Warden not to store the user in the session after the user is authenticated.

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :store => !(request.format.xml? || request.format.json?))
```

Hope that helps whoever sees this thread.

Comment: @kain I believe this is overriding a line in the Devise SessionsController create action.

Comment: authentication controller

Comment: I don't see an authentication controller: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise

Comment: I'm guessing this must be it: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L17

Comment: You forgot to tell that you must set config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :params_auth] in config/initializers/devise.rb for accomplish this override

Comment: Would also like to know how disable warden store session for sign up. This override works great for sign in.

Answer (score 4):

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :store => is_navigational_format?)
```

Answer (score 1):

in theory if you don't use it, it is not loaded now.
up until rails 2.3.8, you could do:

```
# application_controller.rb
session :off, :if => :sessionless_request?

protected

def sessionless_request?(request)
  request.format == :xml || request.format == :json
end
```

now you can do the same with this gem
https://github.com/kares/session_off

Comment: i tried your solutions and it doesn't work. maybe devise and session_off doesn't work well together ?!

Comment: note that the plugin only redefines session call from controller, request.session call will still retrieve session. I think devise (actually warden) uses env['rack.session']  :(

Comment: i'm getting multiple errors when using session_off. i probably have several plugins that use the session.

Comment: that's too bad b/c session_off seems like a great plugin. (btw, devise also uses "session")

Answer (score -4):

You should use "devise :timeoutable" in your model and use config.timeout_in = 0 in config/initializers/devise.rb

Restart your server!