# Devise Custom Strategies: Still Setting Session Cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, devise

I am using Devise to authenticate users to my Ruby on Rails application. Up to this point, I have been using the standard Cookie-based session to authenticate users, but now I have requirements to allow a token-based authentication, and I implemented this through a [custom **Warden** strategy](http://kyan.com/blog/2013/10/11/devise-authentication-strategies).

For the sake of this example, my custom strategy code is:

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class CustomAuthenticatable < Base
      def valid?
        params.has_key? :email
      end 

      def authenticate!
        success!(User.find_by(email: params[:email]))
        #fail
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

So this works as expected for the first request: when I `GET /api/my_controller/url?email=user@example.com` the user is authenticated, and I get the expected response.

**But wait:** when I then make a second request: `GET /api/my_controller/url`, the user is still authenticated.

Upon further inspection, I see that a `Set-Cookie` is being sent, with a Devise session.

### So here's my question:

How do I disable the `Set-Cookie` when using a custom strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the creation of a session, like described in here.

[Prevent session creation on rails 3.2.2 for RESTful api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717667/prevent-session-creation-on-rails-3-2-2-for-restful-api/10723769#10723769)

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :store => !(request.format.xml? || request.format.json?))
```

For some other options, please consider [Rails 3 disabling session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435494/rails-3-disabling-session-cookies).